# Render field directly in page.html.twig

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

How can i render a field directly in the page.html.twig?

When i try to render it like:

```
{{ node.field_my_field.value }}
```

I get:

```
Exception: Object of type Drupal\entity_reference_revisions\EntityReferenceRevisionsFieldItemList cannot be printed
```

When i add a .value, it does still not render right (well i use paragraphs with subfields) but get following error:
User error: "target_id" is an invalid render array key in

```
Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
User error: "target_revision_id" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
User error: "_loaded" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
User error: "_accessCacheability" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children() (line 97 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Element.php).
```

So how can i render it?

Comment: It seems you try to print an EntityReference field, am I right ? Could you give me wich kind of reference (node, user, taxonomy, paragraphs...), & wich fields of this reference you want to render. So I could help you with a complete answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Drupal 8 & Twig you can render a lot of stuff such:

### Render field value

For example, the node title

```
{{ node.title.value }}
```

### Render field entity value

For example, a field of taxonomy term `categories`

```
{{ node.field_categories.entity.name.value }}
```

### Render field value of Paragraph (entity)

You can't print a Paragraph entity in Twig, but you can print every fields

```
{{ node.field_my_field.entity.field_title.value }}
```

In the previous example, `field_title` is a field of my Paragraph.

---

To go further, you could render a display mode using the module `Bamboo Twig`.
 - [Project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/bamboo_twig)
 - [Article about Bamboo Twig](https://antistatique.net/en/we/blog/2018/07/18/bamboo-twig-beyond-twig-in-drupal-8)
 - [Official Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/bamboo-twig)

### Render entity with display mode using Bamboo Twig

After installing the module and enable the submodule `bamboo_twig_loader`.

```
{# Render node with nid 1 #}
{{ bamboo_render_entity('node', 1) }}

{# Render the teaser of node with nid 2 #}
{{ bamboo_render_entity('node', 2, 'teaser') }}
```

### Render field using Bamboo Twig

```
{# Render the title of node 1  #}
{{ bamboo_render_field('title', 'node', 1) }}
```

Hopes it will help you !

Comment: I"m having trouble rendering fields in my twig. I can see that my twig is loading div classes within the region I want it to, but the fields themselves are not appearing in source code.  I know the machine names of the fields, but I am having trouble getting them to appear on the page.  I want to apply classes to each field individually as I have to wrap them within multiple divs for a certain design requirement.

Answer (score 1):

In order to render the field in a twig template, you will need a contrib module; unless you go with the hook_preprocess_page() implementation.

Using Bamboo Twig definitely does your job, as already mentioned in the suggested answer. It seems a bit awkward at first that you have to enable one of its submodules in order to achieve this though.

An alternative and more common solution is to use the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module with which you could do the following (copying from their [cheat sheet](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md)):

```
{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 1) }}
{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 1, 'teaser') }}
{{ drupal_field('field_image', 'node', 1, {type: 'image_url', settings: {image_style: 'large'}}) }}
```